# How do I create a right triangle with CSS that spans 100% the width of the containing element?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to use CSS to place a right triangle within a containing div so that the triangle takes up the full height and width of the containing div.

The height is set to `100px`, so that's easy enough to handle, but the width is variable (essentially 100%) of the screen width, and I can't figure out how to get the triangle to stretch properly for a variable width.

The following is basically what I would like to get on the screen:

[image]

The following markup and CSS is as close as I've been able to get, but the problems I'm running into is that you can't do a percentage for a border width, and setting `100vw` for the border width doesn't account for the vertical scrollbar, which causes the red triangle width to be too wide and thus add horizontal scrollbars to the site.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="triangle">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
}

.triangle {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 100px 0 0 100vw;
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Please note that the question linked to from this question does NOT work. It has the same problem as I noted in this one with using `100vw`. sol's answer below with the linear gradient works, but you get a really jagged edge. As such, I ended up basically using the above CSS, and then adding the following JS to run on page load to fix the scrollbar issue:

Comment: `const scrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;`

Comment: `document.querySelector('.container').style.borderLeftWidth = \`calc(100vw - ${scrollbarWidth}px)\`;`

Comment: This is the only solution I could find that truly worked. If there are any better solutions out there, please let us all know.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment, the DOM selector should be `document.querySelector('.triangle')`, not `document.querySelector('.container')`. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.triangle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, blue 50%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="triangle">
  </div>
```

Comment: sol, I really like the simplicity of this. It's almost a perfect solution except for the fact that the linear gradient creates a really jagged edge. As such, I'm going to continue to look for a better solution.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish almost the same thing, but have that jagged edge as well. Did you find a solution?